# WooCommerce: Webhook disabled on its own

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm developing an order management system that hooks into [WooCommerce](https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/) but the [Webhook](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/webhooks/) behaves irregularly. The [Webhook](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/webhooks/) gets disabled on its own.

I've investigated with the users - none of them have privileges. The administrator hasn't touched this section and hasn't updated any of the plugins.

Are there any reasons this would happen? Maybe returning http errors from my side?

```
WordPress: 4.4.1
WooCommerce: 2.3.8
```

Comment: Why am I downvoted, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I see no information to work off of. There is zero code, there isn't even a name of the webhook in question, which makes it impossible to search around for similar troubles people may have testified about online.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, but I'm confused. Why would there be any code, it's a WooCommerce webhook, it's configured for "order.created", has a secret and is activated. Then suddenly it's disabled.

Comment: How did you configure it? What is the hook's name?

Comment: I really don't understand the relevance of this question. The name is something you choose. Anyhow the `Name: ERP Webhook` `Status: Active `  `Topic: order.created `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently a WooCommerce Webhook will automatically disable due to delivery failure. 
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/webhooks/#section-3

> “Disabled” (does not deliver due delivery failures).

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to fix this every time WooCommerce updates, just create a filter in your child-theme:

```
function overrule_webhook_disable_limit( $number ) {
    return 999999999999; //very high number hopefully you'll never reach.
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_max_webhook_delivery_failures', 'overrule_webhook_disable_limit' );
```

Comment: No need for a function. There's a constant in PHP for that: PHP_INT_MAX; Which is the highest number PHP can handle.

Answer (score 2):

Automatically disabled due to delivery failures (as mentioned above).

Because I'm depending on them a lot and never wants them disabled (no matter what), you can change function called `failed_delivery()` in this file:
`plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-webhook.php`
to this:

```
private function failed_delivery() {

    $failures = $this->get_failure_count();

    if ( $failures > apply_filters( 'woocommerce_max_webhook_delivery_failures', 5 ) ) {

        //$this->update_status( 'disabled' );
        update_post_meta( $this->id, '_failure_count', ++$failures );

    } else {

        update_post_meta( $this->id, '_failure_count', ++$failures );
    }
}
```

and they will never be automagically disabled again.

Comment: Don't EVER edit third party plugins files and even less tell people to do that.

Comment: I have to disagree. What if you want to fix vulnerability yourself which author can't fix on time? Or customise something? Obviously you EDIT third party plugin files. Just know what you're doing and keep it up to date with your changes. Better safe than sorry.